# How can I start my sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2012-localdb

Hi Please I stopped my sql server in order to attach a database and unknowingly I closed the sql studio and now i cant connect to the instance again because I can't start the server

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question, but try this from your command line:

```
C:\> SqlLocalDb start "MyInstance"
```

Where "MyInstance" would be your instance name.

Taken from [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/), which has a good lot of info about setting up and working with SQL LocalDB.

Comment: "Not working" is not much use! If you post up exactly what the error or problem is someone will be able to help.

Comment: Well I got it fixed. For record Purpose, I opened the ms sql management studio, clicked on the view menu, select Registered Servers, this will open the Database engine on the left panel, click and expand the Database engine, expand Local Server Groups and right click on the server name under the local server groups, select Service control and then click start, follow the prompt message and start the server and then you can login to your instance. Thats all though no programming.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it fixed. For record Purpose, I opened the ms sql management studio, clicked on the view menu, select Registered Servers, this will open the Database engine on the left panel, click and expand the Database engine, expand Local Server Groups and right click on the server name under the local server groups, select Service control and then click start, follow the prompt message and start the server and then you can login to your instance. Thats all though no programming.